# Low-Cost Historical Corporate Financials Data?

Tags: finance

For my finance textbook, I would like to recommend data sources that students can afford.  Obviously, Compustat is not affordable.

Are there any low-cost or free data bases that offer basic historical financial statements on US (and maybe non-US) companies in panel format?  I am thinking of just about 10-20 key items for at least 20 years for all US corps: Assets, Current Assets, Liabilities, Current Liabilities, Long-Term Debt, Working Capital, Revenues, Gross Profit, Operating Income, Interest Expense, Income Tax Expense, Net Income, CF Operations, CF Investing, and CF Financing.  Plus a ticker, a period date, and a release date.

Presumably, this could even be scraped from Edgar, but I would rather not have to do this myself.

Pointers appreciated.

/iaw

Answer (score 2):

### iextrading

https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/#financials

- Costs: free
- Data provided: income statements, balance sheets, cash flow statements, EOD price, volume, splits, dividends
- Data format: JSON
- Data access method: RESTful API + websockets (real-time)
- Misc.: excellent documentation, very active github issue tracking
- Drawbacks: historical data goes back by only 2 years

### eodhistoricaldata.com

https://eodhistoricaldata.com/knowledgebase/stock-etfs-fundamental-data-feeds/

- Costs: $10/month
- Data provided: quarterly/yearly income statements, balance sheets, cash flow statements, EOD price, dividends
- Data format: JSON
- Data access method: RESTful API
- Misc.: sign up is very easy, documentation is good
- Drawbacks: I detected missing EOD prices for historical months

### InteractiveBrokers API

https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/fundamentals.html

Note: requires to open a trading account with them. Approval times vary, and might not be suitable to students.

- Costs: sign-up free.
- Data provided: everything (including dividends)
- Data format: depends on the client library (C++, Java, Python)
- Data access method: only via libraries (C++, Java, Python), no RESTful API. (personal opinion: only suitable for people with a very strong developer background).
- Misc.: documentation isn't very good.
- Drawbacks: taking approval time, and time to learn their technical nomenclature  into account, I don't recommend using it for student projects. It's good for professionals.

### Quandl

https://www.quandl.com/databases/SF1

- Costs: $29/month to access 5 years worth of data
- Data provided: 14,000 companies and 150 indicators (alternative data is also provided, but costs more)
- Data format: JSON, CSV, or library specific (R,Python, Matlab, Excel)
- Data access method: RESTful API, and via libraries
- Misc.: documentation + support is very good, excellent data quality
- Drawbacks: the more data you want to access, the more you need to pay.

---

I developed software using all of the above services. eodhistoricaldata.com is my favourite so far.

Comment: can you comment on availability of dividend info?  without it, it is impossible to calculate rates of return.

Comment: Yes, all three services provide dividend information.

Answer (score 1):

I have compiled a pretty exhaustive list on my website: http://the-world-is.com/blog/resources/general-investor-resources/

Particularly, look under the following headings:
"Tools" >> "Research Platforms"
and,
"Data" >> "Fundamental Financial Data"

There are a lot resources there to get you started. Personally, I use [Portfolio123](https://www.portfolio123.com/mvnforum/pubprofile?member=primus&sref=18416/) which might also be appropriate for your purposes. It has several panel-based displays of financial data, some of which are customizable. Moreover, its core data holdings are actually derived from Compustat yet it is much more affordable than purchasing a license to Capital IQ.

In this business, you often get what you pay for. I believe that paying a little coin for premium data is well worth the cost, especially since the costs have come down significantly for retail investors.

Comment: yes, I think one does get what one pays for.  this is very useful for students that need relatively little and pay relatively little.  PS: I will also be glad to reference your list in my book!

Answer (score 1):

Idk if anyone is still looking for a free resource still but [MarketBeat](https://www.marketbeat.com/) has Quarterly, TTM and 10 yr annual data for Income statement, balance sheet and cashflow for free. Idk if they have an API but they let you download a csv for spreadsheets. Note on a rare occasions they wont have the financials. I found that if it happens, it's only on the small caps